# Did both temperature of nernst equation same

Tags: electrochemistry, nernst-equation

I saw the nernst equation[image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/JJGRJVcj4wgc1vQs8]

I have a doubt.Did the temparature at which Standard potential is measured is also the temparature at which electrode potential is measured.
I mean Did the temperature (T) in the equation should always taken as the standard temperature at which Standard potential is measured.
See the below link
https://photos.app.goo.gl/EPxTHcPZ4Tynwvqc6
https://photos.app.goo.gl/cAbVFVHexCPgPXE88

## In the above given Links it was written

## V(metal)-V(solution)=kT/ze×ln{C(reference)/C(metal)} +kT/ze×ln{C(solution)/C(reference)}

Here kT/ze×ln{Preference/C solution}=V electrode

Comment: The factor $\ce{2.3 RT/zF}$ is valid at any temperature, not necessarily at  25°C. If you considering working at $25$°C, and only in this case, this factor can be simplified into $\ce{0.0591/z}$

Comment: @Maurice 0.0591 V/z

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia webpage [Standard electrode potential (data page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)). The standard potentials are taken at 25°C. Since the half-cells are for real chemical reactions, the potential of the half-cell can be corrected for temperature using the Nernst equation.